# how to turn off buffering in react-player?

Tags: reactjs, react-player

when I try to play the next video it does not start and I guess the problem is buffering.
P.S my url is video.m3u8 files
It works fine, but when i change url nothing happens, i would like to know how can i stop current video and load a new one whe, url changes ?

here's my rewind function

```
const showVideo = async () => {
sessionStorage.setItem("sPlayerLinkId", params.id);
const body = new FormData();
const mac = window.TvipStb.getMainMacAddress();

body.append("link_id", params.id);
body.append("mac", mac);

let response = await fetch(getVideo, {
  method: "POST",
  body: body,
});
let data = await response.json();
if (data.error) {
  openDialog("crush");
  return 0;
}

if (_isMounted.current) setVideoLink(data.response.url);  };

var goToNext = function () {
playerRef.current.seekTo(0, "seconds");
setVideoLink(null);
if (playerInfo.next_id) {
  params.id = playerInfo.next_id;
  showVideo();
} else navigate(-1);};

<ReactPlayer
    url={videoLink}
    playing={isPlaying}
    ref={playerRef}
    key={params.id}
    onProgress={() => {
      current();
    }}
    config={{
      file: {
        forceHLS: true,
      },
    }}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you build your own player from scratch using just react and a style library.

I had similar issues using react-player and I had to resort to building my own custom player in which I could now ensure that buffering is handled the way I expect it to.

I handled buffering using the `progress` event as follows

```
    const onProgress = () => {
      if (!element.buffered) return;
      const bufferedEnd = element.buffered.end(element.buffered.length - 1);
      const duration = element.duration;
      if (bufferRef && duration > 0) {
        bufferRef.current!.style.width = (bufferedEnd / duration) * 100 + "%";
      }
    };
```

- `element.buffered` represents a collection of buffered time ranges.
- `element.buffered.end(element.buffered.length - 1)` gets the time at the end of the buffer range. With this value, I was able to compute the current buffer range and update the buffer progress accordingly.

I ended up writing an article that would help others learn to [build an easily customizable player](https://awacreates.com/blog/implement-buffering-in-react--a-complete-guide) from scratch using just React and any style library (in this case charkra UI was used).